# Rails model test error/failure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing

Let me start off with saying that I'm fairly new to testing in Rails. I'm getting some errors in my tests and I don't quite know why.

```
rails test:models
Run options: --seed 21021

# Running:

F

Failure:
UserTest#test_user_should_be_valid [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/models/user_test.rb:9]:
Expected false to be truthy.


bin/rails test test/models/user_test.rb:8

E

Error:
PostTest#test_post_should_be_valid:
ArgumentError: When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument.
    test/models/post_test.rb:5:in `setup'


bin/rails test test/models/post_test.rb:8



Finished in 0.237740s, 8.4126 runs/s, 4.2063 assertions/s.
2 runs, 1 assertions, 1 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

Here's the code

## user_test

```
require 'test_helper'

class UserTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @user=User.new(email:"fo0@hotmail.com")
  end

  test "user should be valid" do
    assert @user.valid?
  end
end
```

## post_test

```
require 'test_helper'

class PostTest < ActiveSupport::TestCase
  def setup
    @post=Post.new(:ruby_meetup)
  end

  test "post should be valid" do
    assert @post.valid?
  end

end
```

## user.rb

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
         has_many :posts

          has_many :rsvps
          has_many :posts, through: :rsvps

          validates :email, presence: true

end
```

## post.rb

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user
 geocoded_by :address
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj){ obj.address.present? and obj.address_changed? }
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude
after_validation :reverse_geocode


  has_many :rsvps
  has_many :users, through: :rsvps

  validates :name, presence: true

end
```

Comment: The test failures state that `User.new(email:"fo0@hotmail.com")` and `Post.new(:ruby_meetup)` are invalid records. What are the errors? (have you looked at e.g. `@user.errors.messages`?) What are the `User` and `Post` models? Perhaps you have some other validation rule(s) in there, such as `validates :name, presence: true`? You haven't shown us the models, nor the error message, so I can only speculate what the cause might be.

Comment: `@post=Post.new(:ruby_meetup)` you are passing a Symbol as argument, whereas the constructor expect a hash, why are not affecting a value to this symbol ? for example `Post.new ruby_meetup: true` or `Post.new type: :ruby_meetup` , please put your code for Post model so we can help more precisely

Comment: the first "error" is saying that you were expecting `@user.valid?` to be `true`, but it isn't. So, you might have some validations in your User model that require more than just the email. As for the second error, it comes from doing `Post.new(:ruby_meetup)`, `ruby_meetup` is a key, and `Post.new` expects a hash as parameter, just like what you did in `User.new(email:"fo0@hotmail.com")`

Comment: `PostTest` tell you what you're doing wrong quite explicitly: "When assigning attributes, you must pass a hash as an argument." `:ruby_meetup` is not a hash, you're missing the key.

Comment: alright sorry about that I've added both the post model and the user model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't show anything about your `User` model, it's impossible to know why it's not valid. But, in your test, you could do something like:

```
puts @user.errors.full_messages
```

And see what the problem is.

On that second error, the error messages is telling you exactly what is wrong. You are not passing a `hash` in the `new`, you're passing a symbol:

```
def setup
  @post=Post.new(:ruby_meetup)
end
```

`:ruby_meetup` should be something like:

```
ruby_meetup: 'some_value'
```

Comment: i've now added the post model and user model thanks.

Comment: What did you get from `@user.errors.full_messages`? Did you change the `symbol` to a `hash` and did that resolve the second error?

Comment: I get a no method error when I put @user.errors.full_messages

Comment: lso for the second one I'm getting an unknown attribute error.     @post=Post.new(ruby_meetup: 'true')
This is how my code looks like maybe I've coded it wrong? edit: I've changed the code to look like this     @post=Post.new(user_id: "1") and now I'm getting the same error as my user.test

Comment: in my user_test.rb file?

Comment: I'm getting the same error message as before, Failure: UserTest#test_user_should_be_valid [/home/ubuntu/workspace/test/models/user_test.rb:9]: Expected false to be truthy.

Comment: In your console, you should see the output of your `puts` statement. In addition to the test error message that you are mentioning.

Comment: Thats not the case, I'm only getting the test error message.

Answer (score 0):

The error has been solved.  I put this code in my user_test.rb

```
assert @user.valid?, @user.errors.full_messages
```

and fixed the error which was I left the password empty.

Thank you everyone for the help, I do appreciate it.